# Find ActiveRecord object by maximum field value of a child object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I find the object associated with the results of an ActiveRecord Calculation rather than a value?

For example I have @parent which has many children. I would like to find the child with the maximum 'value'.

I understand that I can do @parent.children.maximum(:value), but this returns the maximum value. Is there a method similar to maximum and minimum that returns the entire object instead of the value so that I can use different fields from the maximum object?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
@parent.children.order("value DESC").first
```

Comment: Could this cause AR to return an array of multiple objects, then select just the first?  Or is ARel smart enough to insert a "limit 1" clause?

Comment: `first` as `last` for AR object will add `limit 1` to sql. you can try it: `@parent.children.order("value DESC").first.to_sql`

Comment: On Postgres this does not work as expected if you have NULL values in the value column. The will-ayd answer works to find the real max value in this case.

Comment: downvoted big time since you are actually doing NlogN work where you only need N complexity, re-ordering elements in multiple iterations where it's only enough to do 1 iteration. This code is a reason for a slowdown of a service we have at work

Comment: @Alehar if you have got some kind of a tree index in your database on this particular column it will be O(logN). And if you don't -- then go with Will's solution. Which will be slow as well. So the solution is specific to your database setup. Generally if you want to do such kind of queries -- you should add an index to the column.

Comment: @Phil in postgres you can order specifying nulls last or nulls first

Answer (score 27):

Not sure if this is the most efficient but once you have the maximum value you can pass that along in a hash to get the object

```
@maxvalue = @parent.children.maximum(:value)
@myObject = @parent.children.where(:value => @maxvalue)
```

Comment: it will return an Array of objects, niether an object

Comment: a minute too late i suppose.  fl00r probably has the best suggestion

Comment: also true.  fl00r's suggestion will guaranteed only return one.  if you have multiple objects sharing the same maximum value this will give you an array back

Comment: This is actually more of what I need (in the end), I should have asked it that way so I could have accepted your answer :). fl00r's is more accurate in regards to the question though. So, for posterity's sake, I've accepted his.

Comment: @justinxreese you should un-accept fl00r's answer then and accept this one.

Comment: no hard feelings.  might just want to edit your question though to make it more inline with whichever one you choose as an answer :-)

Answer (score 10):

This is my personal favorite when it comes to readability, by using ruby's [#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) :

```
@parent.children.max_by(&:value)
```

Comment: I can't imagine this being the most efficient way but it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
@parent.children.first(:conditions => {:value => @parent.children.maximum(:value)})
```