# Ruby ActiveRecord Maximum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working with a Rails app that I need to return the maximum value for a particular row but also need to return the rest of the row contents.

Code:

```
medias = Media.maximum(:id, :conditions => ['medias.image = true AND medias.subscriber_id  = 37'], :group => ['subscriber_id'])
```

This is only returning the id and subscriber_id, I need to return all of the rows not just those two.

Example: In my medias table a subscriber can upload multiple photos. I am trying to group by the subscriber id and get the last entry for all subscribers. So basically I need a find all by maximum.

Comment: `maximum value for a particular row` ? In that case, which fields are involved in the maximum calculation?

Comment: Add some sample data so that people helping you don't have to invent their own in order to help you.

Comment: Well a subscriber can upload multiple photos. I am wanting to get every subscribers latest upload. So say if a subscriber uploads 4 photos, say a month ago, and I am looping through each subscriber photo I need to be able to get the last row for each subscriber... does that make sense?

Comment: I know what you mean; I was saying that me is too lazy to whip up a table with sample data in order to help you solve the problem. So, if there was sample data that I could quickly dump into a table, then I, lazy, would have tried to help. But that's just me, today.

Comment: What you're looking for is a SQL like : `SELECT MAX(last_update_at) FROM medias GROUP BY subscriber_id;`

Answer (score 6):

```
medias = Media.maximum(:id, :conditions => ['medias.image = true AND medias.subscriber_id  = 37'], :group => ['subscriber_id'])
trythis = Media.find(medias)
```

Comment: Tried this and its not working. Here is the error: `migrate_photo.rb:21:in each: undefined method id for [37, 137]:Array (NoMethodError)` I have updated my description above with more information

Comment: `trythis = Media.find(medias)`

Comment: Tried that and I get `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:296:in 'find_one': Couldn't find Media with ID={37=>137} (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`

Comment: funny :) it should work. Try this `trythis = Media.find_all_by_id(medias)`

Comment: which version of rails do you use?

Comment: and you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060280/find-activerecord-object-by-maximum-field-value/5060332#5060332

Comment: @dennismonsewicz are you modifying the code fl00r has given in *any way at all* ?

Comment: @Zabba, no I am simply taking what he is giving me and testing it out.

Comment: Oh, looks like the ID being search for is `{37, 137}`, a hash, instead of being an array `[37, 137]`.

Comment: To be clear, yes, summary functions will return an ordered hash of ids. You can run `.keys` on that hash, and then feed that array to a `find_all_by` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Media.order("subscriber_id DESC").limit(1).where("image = true").where("subscriber_id = ?", 37)
```

I think you're wanting to find the max subscriber_id, but if not, just replace that with what you're ordering on

Comment: This will work for a particular user, what if I was wanting to find ALL media objects but group by subscriber id

Comment: So you want the latest media for each subscriber?